# Unir dos tablas en una sola en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo las siguientes consultas:

```
SELECT *
FROM #TABLE_AR_5

SELECT *
FROM #TABLE_AR_6
```

Este es mi resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que la información quede en una sola tabla, busco este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aplicas la sentencia inner JOIN con el campo TERRITORIAL
Ejemplo:

```
SELECT TABLE_AR_5.TERRITORIAL,TABLE_AR_5.ENE,TABLE_AR_6.FEB
FROM TABLE_AR_5
INNER JOIN TABLE_AR_6 ON TABLE_AR_6.TERRITORIAL=TABLE_AR_5.TERRITORIAL
```

Otra opción seria con UNION